# Errant line spacing issue with new Docs, ignoring 'Add space after paragraph' on page break

Tags: google-docs

New documents have suddenly started exhibiting strange behaviour, and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. The main symptom is that on the page break, there is no gap between paragraphs. This is very annoying because at a glance, it makes it seem part of the previous paragraph, particularly if the text happens to align near the end of the page. However, upon closer testing and inspection, there is also a very slightly different line spacing between paragraphs, as it now fits 28 lines instead of 27.

[Line Space Present](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12CvoUfX1GAlqLBC0dOJlRR2I_6EwEtIbvgWmJoXADd4/edit?usp=sharing)

[Line Space Missing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v5-S7bKJBl_IbgxFl0s4hhE21Qfxg9_tDd8oHwvXANg/edit?usp=sharing)

[Comparison](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x8pnlKKpAA8g4u5M_iDoK0HgD01u4v7qV8Ik2I7eiq8/edit?usp=sharing)

(Turn off Print Mode once you get into the document and scroll down to the page break)

[image: Comparison]

I have been through every setting I can find. It's not custom spacing, those are identical, it's not the header or footer, it's not the page size, it's not the margins, it's not the style, it's not the text itself (copy+pasted from one doc to the other, even copied out and inspected the HTML output). There seems to be no reason for this. And yet, the desired style persists if I make a copy of an existing document - which I can do, it's just annoying - which suggests it is some property of the document somewhere. It's the same if I create the doc on desktop or through the app, and I've also tried setting the default styles via updating the Normal style and then setting it to the default. Completely clearing all styles still leaves a difference between the documents.

Comparing the two (otherwise identical) docs shows a change "Format page: background colour, bottom margin, left margin, right margin, size, top margin" includes the difference, although all those settings are identical.

[Also reported here.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/72287607)

EDIT: I tried creating a new document on a separate account, and it did the same thing, and I was just shared a new document by someone else which is also doing it. I'm guessing this is some new formatting default for Google Docs that we have no control over.

Comment: It looks that the pages aren't of the same size (see the rulers). What are the size of each of the documents shown in the snapshots?

Comment: @Rubén I noticed that, but it's a red herring. In Print Layout, the pages and margins are the same size, it's just trimming it differently in this view. Both are just a standard A4 page, 21x29.7cm with 2.54cm margins all around.